# What's the best term to refer to the pointy part of a comic-book-style balloon UI element?

Tags: help, tooltips, terminology

[image]

In discussing balloon-ish UI elements, I've described the pointy part as 'points', 'arrows' or 'spikes', and that seems to get the idea across to many people alright... but I find myself falling back on hand gestures to clarify my err... point.

What's the best (or proper?) term/phrase to use to describe this anatomical part?

**UPDATE**

It appears the consensus is that they are generally referred to as **tails**.

What I find challenging now is that in contemporary UI's, these 'tails' tend to be much stubbier (and the balloons more rectangular) than their comic-book inspiration (more bunny-tail than cat-tail?).  I feel like my days of hand gestures and blithering may not yet be over!

Comment: The reason why they are more rigid in UIs is that this makes text layout and drawing easier. In your above screenshot, text can be left-aligned and wrapped inside a rectangle. With traditional ellipsoid balloons, you need to center the text, wrap to an ellipsis and draw using bezier paths. Your shape above only needs circle segments and straight lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the balloon is technically referred to as a "callout." Most websites I've seen call the pointy part a "tail."

http://www.techsmith.com/learn/snagit/mac/1/written/feedback/

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, Wikipedia calls them tails too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_balloon

Comment: Ooh, great history.  (Kind of embarrassed I hadn't been there yet!)